# Apache2 PHP - How do I use .htaccess to rewrite direct download links

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a directory of files which are downloaded by users package managers using the direct link to the file.
I'm trying to set up file logging, so I can get statistics on the downloads. I’m using this script I found on GitHub: https://github.com/iNamik/PHP-Download-Tracker

- I'm using the above script that consists of a files directory, a log directory, and an index.php which lists the files to download.
- Index.php lists all files in the download directory. This file can be renamed to anything, i.e. download.php
- If I use the index.php and click on the file I want to download, it logs the information and downloads it.
- If I use the direct link to the file (/downloadfolder/file.exe) the index.php is bypassed and nothing is logged.

Is it possible to use something like mod_rewrite in Apache, to add download.php?file= before the file name in the direct link?

Example:

1. Access this Direct link: https://exampledomain.com/files/file.pdf --> this does not get logged. File transfer starts.
2. Have it be automatically rewritten to: https://exampldomain.com/files/download.php?file=file.pdf --> This does get logged. And the file transfer starts

Comment: How does the user get a direct link to the file?   The solution to this is usually to ensure that all your links go through the tracker.

Comment: It’s an APT Repo. Users download files from their Package managers on their Phones. The direct download location is stored in the Packages.gz file that is read by the package manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hair pulling and testing using a htaccess tester, this is what I came up with.

My download.php is inside the files directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /files/
RewriteRule ^(.+(file|FILE))$ download.php?file=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will redirect anything that doesn't exist to index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I not exactly what I had in mind.

Users download files directly from example.com/files/example.exe
I want the URL to be rewritten to: example.com/files/download.php?file=example.exe